# Select value based on two parameters : another column string value and max(date) with BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table :

```
AccountID   Email              status_update  value   date (dd/mm/yyyy) 
123456      foo@gmail.com      state1          19     02/02/2016
123456      foo@gmail.com      state2          20     10/10/2014
123456      foo@gmail.com      state2          35     15/10/2015
456123      bar@gmail.com      state2          45     05/04/2017
789123      foobar@gmail.com   state2          10     22/04/2016
789123      foobar@gmail.com   state1          22     17/06/2018
456345      cool@gmail.com     state1          10     13/08/2017
456345      cool@gmail.com     state2          05     09/07/2015
456345      cool@gmail.com     state2          17     09/07/2014
```

How do I return the earliest value when `status_update = state2`?

So for example looking at my table for `foo@gmail.com` I would like to get `20`. Which is the earliest value (`10/10/2014`) of `state2` for this account.

As you might guess, I can't use a simple `where status_update = state2` statement here since this is part of a more global query where the final output will be grouped by AccountID and Email.

Basically what I would like to be able to do this

`ARRAY_AGG(value WHERE status_update = state2 ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET (0)] as Account_Status`

or something like this :

`(value when MIN(CASE WHEN status_update = state2 THEN created END)) as EarliestValue`

Hopefully my question is clear. Thanks.

Comment: not clear enough (at least to me) - i would recommend to show expected output - final output. from my practice - asking how to do something in the middle ( `part of a more global query` ) usually ends up with new questions and redoing anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
ARRAY_AGG(IF(status_update = state2, value, NULL)
          IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET (0)] as Account_Status
```

It enables you to filter out updates other than those matching `state2`.

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL (assuming you do not want any grouping and just want to label each account with account state based on earliest state2 row in that account)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *,
  FIRST_VALUE(IF(status_update = 'state2', value, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY email, accountid 
      ORDER BY PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', dt) 
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
  ) account_Status
FROM `project.dataset.table`
-- ORDER BY accountid, email, PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', dt)
```

You can test/play with above using dummy data from your question as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 123456 accountid, 'foo@gmail.com' email, 'state1' status_update, 19 value, '02/02/2016' dt UNION ALL
  SELECT 123456, 'foo@gmail.com', 'state2', 20, '10/10/2014' UNION ALL
  SELECT 123456, 'foo@gmail.com', 'state2', 35, '15/10/2015' UNION ALL
  SELECT 456123, 'bar@gmail.com', 'state2', 45, '05/04/2017' UNION ALL
  SELECT 789123, 'foobar@gmail.com', 'state2', 10, '22/04/2016' UNION ALL
  SELECT 789123, 'foobar@gmail.com', 'state1', 22, '17/06/2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 456345, 'cool@gmail.com', 'state1', 10, '13/08/2017' UNION ALL
  SELECT 456345, 'cool@gmail.com', 'state2', 05, '09/07/2015' UNION ALL
  SELECT 456345, 'cool@gmail.com', 'state2', 17, '09/07/2014' 
)
SELECT *,
  FIRST_VALUE(IF(status_update = 'state2', value, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY email, accountid 
      ORDER BY PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', dt) 
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
  ) account_Status
FROM `project.dataset.table`
ORDER BY accountid, email, PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', dt)
```

which comes with below result

```
Row accountid   email               status_update   value   dt          account_Status   
1   123456      foo@gmail.com       state2          20      10/10/2014  20   
2   123456      foo@gmail.com       state2          35      15/10/2015  20   
3   123456      foo@gmail.com       state1          19      02/02/2016  20   
4   456123      bar@gmail.com       state2          45      05/04/2017  45   
5   456345      cool@gmail.com      state2          17      09/07/2014  17   
6   456345      cool@gmail.com      state2          5       09/07/2015  17   
7   456345      cool@gmail.com      state1          10      13/08/2017  17   
8   789123      foobar@gmail.com    state2          10      22/04/2016  10   
9   789123      foobar@gmail.com    state1          22      17/06/2018  10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try window function like below. Order by Status desc and date asc and select the first row. You will get the desired row and do any more operations if needed. I haven't recreated the sample table and tested this but I hope you get the idea

```
 SELECT
    AccountID,
    value as min_value
   FROM
    (
         SELECT
            AccountID,
            Email,
            status_update,
            value,
            DATE,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountID ORDER BY status_update DESC DATE ASC) row_num
           FROM
            <tablename> ) temp_tab
  WHERE
    temp_tab.row_num = 1
```